# Count checked CheckedListBox items

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have CheckedListBox and four item in it!
Now I want to count number of checked item. 
For this I use:

```
 countnumber=CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count
```

But countnumber is always 0 even if I checked CheckedListBox items or not!

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you ever figured this out ? I have the same problem here.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a similar issue where I wanted to disable a button if nothing was checked and I had `cbl.CheckedItems.Count` inside the ItemChecked Event.

```
    Private Sub cbl_Check(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles cbl_overrides.ItemCheck
        Dim count As Integer = cbl.CheckedItems.Count
        ...
    End Sub
```

On the first call count is always 0, but it you check a second item then count will be 1.

Form the class docs [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Remarks
>
> The check state is not updated until after the ItemCheck event occurs.

If you are in the ItemChecked event and want an accurate count you need

```
    Private Sub cbl_Check(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles cbl_overrides.ItemCheck
        Dim count As Integer = cbl.CheckedItems.Count
        If e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked
            count -= 1
        ElseIf e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked
            count += 1
        End If
        ...
    End Sub
```

Note: this will count items in an indeterminate state as well as checked items as `CheckedItems` returns indeterminate items as well as checked items.

Answer (score 0):

Show us your code.
`CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count` should work, just like `CheckedListBox1.CheckedIndices.Count`, so you should show us some code if you want us to pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is, put the below in either the "ItemCheck" Event, or the "IndexChanged" Event. 
As you check / uncheck the items, it will alert the current count as you go along.

```
MsgBox(CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count)
```

or

```
Dim count as Integer = 0
count = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count
MsgBox(count)
```

I actually stumbled on this page looking for a way to restrict the number of choices, which does require counting them (kind of related), but I'm probably slightly off topic. Nonetheless, I had a few attempts myself, saw multiple methods elsewhere on how to achieve it, and was surprised how overly complex most examples are. I came up with the below, as the simplest way of restricting the number of choices. I'm in no way a professional programmer, i do this as a self-taught hobby. 
But maybe others will find this useful, as limiting the number of choices is a common constraint you might want to implement.

```
' VB.NET Example
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' Lets say you have 5 x possible options, but only want to allow 2 x selections maximum
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'    1. On the Form itself, Create "1 x CheckedListBox" with "5 x Collection items"
'       (These will represent the "5 x options" to choose from) 

'    2. Create a Global / public Variable to define the "2 x Selection limit" 
'       (as shown in below example, with the variable "choiceLimit")

'    3. The "count" of items is calcualted in the "IndexChanged" event, 
'       because its gets called before the "ItemCheck" event 

'    4. Finally, the actual logic goes in the "ItemCheck" event, 
'       if the current number of checked items is at the limit, 
'       it overrides the event and auto-UNchecks further selections, which enforces the limit. 
'       if you create a new form, add a checklistbox, then copy the code below it works


' Make these Variables Public / Global so they can be accessed by both events below
Dim countItemsChecked As Integer = 0
Dim choiceLimit As Integer = 2

' IndexChanged Event
Private Sub CheckedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    ' whenever an item is selected / reselected it re-counts the number of checked items. 
    countItemsChecked = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count
End Sub

' ItemCheck Event
Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck
    ' if the current checked items is at the limit, then
    If CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count >= choiceLimit Then
        ' if the current item selected was alreday checked...
        If e.CurrentValue = CheckState.Checked Then
            ' ... just uncheck it
            e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked
        Else
            ' ... Otherwise alert "Choice Limit Reached"
            MsgBox("Choice limit reached!")
            ' and override the itemCheck State to force it back to being "UNChecked" 
            e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

and without the comments, the full code is:

```
Dim countItemsChecked As Integer = 0
Dim choiceLimit As Integer = 2

' IndexChanged Event
Private Sub CheckedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    countItemsChecked = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count
End Sub

' ItemCheck Event
Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck
    If CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count >= choiceLimit Then
        If e.CurrentValue = CheckState.Checked Then
            e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked
        Else
            MsgBox("Choice limit reached!")
            e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```